# How To Hide Certain column if User Choose filter,Sorting or Grouping in xtraGridView Devexpress Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, windows-forms-designer, devexpress-windows-ui

How To Hide Certain column if User Choose **filter,Sorting or Grouping** in xtraGridView Devexpress Windows Form

I have done some thing like that

```
 private void gridView1_GridMenuItemClick(object sender, GridMenuItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            //WHEN TO DISPALY CLBAL COL AND WHEN NOT
            if (e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Group By This Column") || e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Sort Ascending") || e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Sort Descending")
                                            || e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Group By This Column") || e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Show Auto Filter Row"))
            {

                gridColumn16.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Clear Grouping") || e.DXMenuItem.Caption.Equals("Clear All Sorting"))
            {
                gridColumn16.Visible = true;
            }

        }
```

I have achieve grouping and sorting but how to know when user perform filtering from column header

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.Share the code you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a GridView level events to customize grid layout when a filter is applied to the grid.  For instance the [ColumnFilterChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ColumnFilterChangedtopic) event

```
gridView1.ColumnFilterChanged += (s, e) => { gridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; };
```

However, this event should fire on any filter changes i.e. from code, from the auto filter row filter row and so on.

There is no universal way to find out what a UI element is caused filter changes, but you can use UI based events (like showing filter popup or activating an editor in a the auto filter row) to accomplisht this task.

Comment: is there any way to find out wheather user is performing any operation wheather he is doing grouping,filtering or sorting

Comment: how to show the column again when user clear the filter option